# What does the following mod_rewrite code do?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I was wondering what does the following mod_rewrite code do, can someone explain the code in detail?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line by line interpretation:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Will be interpreted first and match every request (matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query string). `.*` is a regular expression to match all the time. A better and faster rule might be:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

`^` in regex means, match every string that has a beginning. This is equal to `.*` -> match every thing.

After a match was found, the processing will continue with the `RewriteCond`(itions).
The two RewriteConditions are chained by a invisible logic `AND`. This block will only match if both RewriteConditions are true.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # Check if given file is not a file AND 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # Check if given directory is not a file and
```

Example: If you'll have the following file structure on the server.

```
.
|-- css
|   `-- base.css
|-- img
|   `-- logo.png
`-- index.php
```

If you request the URL example.com/**css/base.css** the following steps will happen.

1. Match for RewriteRule (match all the time)
2. Won't match `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`, because `css/base.css` is a file.
3. `RewriteRule` will be skipped because no match occurred, processing will test other rules and conditions*

If you request the URL example.com/**en/about** the following steps will happen.

1. Match for `RewriteRule` (match all the time)
2. Match `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`, because `en/about` is no file.
3. Match `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`, because `en/about` is no directory.
4. Combination of `RewriteRule` and `RewriteCond` created a positive match ->
5. Redirect the request to `index.php` with the flag `L`

The flag `L` means **last rule**, which will stop the processing. More on [flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags).

This rule combination is often used to redirect all request to an single entry point of an web application. To avoid serving static content by `index.php`, files and directories will be served by web server and not by the index.php. The dispatching of the dynamic site request will be done inside the logic of `index.php`.

* The correct data flow can be found [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/images/rewrite_rule_flow.png)

Answer (score 3):

It rewrites all requests which does not match a file (`(!-f)`) or directory(`(!-d)`) on disk to index.php. `[L]` tells mod_rewrite to stop processing rules after this one.